# Replacing part of a string using a lookup table

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I have two data frames:

DF1: One string column of 200 rows

DF2: Two columns of 130 rows:

- The first column has a substring contained in DF1$messy
- The second column has another string with the proper nomenclature.

Looks like this

```r
DF1: 
-----------------
|   messy   |

| abc.'123_c |

| def.'456_c |

| hij.'789_c |


DF2:
-----------------
|   old_str      |    new_str    |

|    123         |      aa       |

|    789         |      cc       |
```

I need a way to bring in the field DF2$new_str into DF1, by matching the field DF1$messy to the substring DF2$old_str

I first tried writing a for loop, expecting that the the function would apply over the entirety of the columns:

```r
    df1$new.str <- 0
    correct_field <-
     for (i in 1:nrow(df1)){ 
      IF (df1$messy[i] == df2$old_str)
      df1$clean[i] = df2$new_str
    }
```

Second I tried the `difference_left_join` function:

```r
    library(dplyr)
    library(fuzzyjoin)
    test<-difference_left_join(df1, df2, by = c(cut = 'Data.Lake.Field' )
```

(I renamed the join column in both sets 'Data.Lake.Field')

Desired Output:

```r
-----------------
|   messy      |    new_str    |

|    abc.'123_c         |      aa       |

|    def.'456_c         |     NULL      |

|    hij.'789_c         |      cc       |
```

EDIT: 
I think, theoretically, the best was to tackle this would be a FOR loop, with a new column in DF1 that takes a row [i] in DF1$messy, and searches for a match in DF2$old, and populates the field with the exact value of DF2$new that correlates to that DF2$old value. I'm not sure how to do this, as using the [i] suffix to a row always returns that same row number... For example, how would I take a a row - say, DF1$messy[142] - and create a fuzzy match with, say DF2$old[15], and create a new column that returns DF2$new[15] ???

Comment: I don't know if I would consider this a case for `fuzzyjoin` necessarily, if the matching terms are actually represented in the original strings (i.e., you are matching part of a string, not trying to match based on incorrect spelling).

Comment: The single quote might cause problems. You should use dput to produce an unambiguous represetnation of hte data objects.

Comment: I think, theoretically, the best was to tackle this would be a FOR loop, with a new column in DF1 that takes a row [i] in DF1$messy, and searches for a match in DF2$old, and populates the field with the exact value of DF2$new that correlates to that DF2$old value.

I'm not sure how to do this, as using the [i] suffix to a row always returns that same row number... 

For example, how would I take a a row - say, DF1$messy[142]  - and create a fuzzy match with, say DF2$old[15], and create a new column that returns DF2$new[15] ???

Comment: Seconding @42's comment that it would be easier if you include more of your data and code, so that we can better see what the issue is.

Comment: Close vote rationale: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."

Answer (score 2):

You can collapse your search terms and match them with the 'messy' terms in the original data. Then use the matches to join the data frames.

```r
df1 <- data.frame(messy=c('abc','def','ghi'),stringsAsFactors = F)
df2 <- data.frame(old=c('ab','ef','hi'),new=c(1:3),
                  stringsAsFactors = F)

df2$messy <- grep(paste(df2$old,collapse = '|'),df1$messy,value = T)

left_join(df2,df1)

Joining, by = "messy"
  old new messy
1  ab   1   abc
2  ef   2   def
3  hi   3   ghi
```

Comment: I tried this but the error I got was: Warning message:
Column `Data.Lake.Field` joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector .... Looking at what the paste function did, it created a whole lot of noie and a VERY long string that was identical across rows.